# Innodb Tables Do Not Exist

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, innodb

System Type: 64-bit
Windows Edition: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
Microsoft Windows Server: 6.1
MySQL Workbench Version: 6.3

I manage a multi-site WordPress and it has grown to 33,000 tables so it's getting really slow. So I'm trying to optimize our installation. I've been working on a DEV server and end up deleting the whole site. Assuming that copying the live server is not an option at this point (and please trust me that it isn't) can you please help me with the following:

I highlighted and copied tables from the live server to paste them into the DEV server folder. Workbench recognizes the table in the Schemas area but when I write a SELECT query, for an Innodb tables, it says that they don't exist. The MyISAM tables, however, run successfully.

I'm just confused because I know the tables are in the right folder but for some reason they don't query. I saw a solution that says to create the tables with a regular query and then overwrite them in the folder but this isn't realistic for me because there are 33,000 tables. Do any of you have some ideas as to how I can get these Innodb tables working again?

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* copy individual InnoDB tables via the file system.

You can use "transportable tablespaces" to do such.  See the documentation for the *MySQL* version you are using.  (This is *not* the same version as for `Workbench`.)

It is not wise to do the above, but it is possible.  Instead, you *should* use some dump/load mechanism, such as `mysqldump` or `xtrabackup`.

WordPress has the design flaw of letting you get to 33,000 tables.  This puts a performance strain on the OS because of all the files involved.

In moving to InnoDB, I recommend you carefully thing through the choices of `innodb_file_per_table`.  The thoughts involve which MySQL you are using, how big the tables are, and whether you will be using "transportable tablespaces".

I do have one strong recommendation for changing indexes in WP:  See slide 63 of http://mysql.rjweb.org/slides/cook.pdf .  It will improve performance on many of the queries.